# mongoimport fails - out of memory

Tags: mongodb, import

Importing a json (mongoexport from unix machine) on a windows machine with mongod breaks my local db.

dated:1 upsert:1 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) w:117382 117ms

Tue Dec 18 01:00:02 [conn2] MapViewOfFileEx for C:/xampp/mongo/data/test.9 failed with errno:8  Not enough memory available. (file size is 536608768) in MemoryMappedFile::map

Tue Dec 18 01:00:02 [conn2]  test.gmd Fatal Assertion 16166

Tue Dec 18 01:00:02 [conn2] mongod.exe    ???

...

***aborting after fassert() failure

Any tip, how to use mongoimport for importing this json with ~5-GB without crashing the mongo server on windows?

Comment: -1 for using MongoDB 32 bit in production.

Comment: Oo... the windows notebook at the company is not 64bit. btw. it is only a local system for testing :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server must be hosting a 32-bit mongod on  32-bit windows platform, which limits virtual address space to 2GB. That's why the mongodb run out of memory. A 64-bit system will solve this issue.

Comment: that's it. after trying the same on a 64bit windows pc at home, it runs. thx

Comment: Had the same issue on a raspberry 64bit,